# what command should I use to see the ip address of WinCE os?The ipconfig does not work

Tags: windows-mobile

Use the same i.e. with the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ipconfig may be included in the OS by the OEM.  If it's not there, then you don't have a command-line option to get the IP address.  You would have to write your own, but it's pretty simple.  Just query the registry key here:

`[HKLM\comm\[adapter name]\Parms\Tcpip\IpAddress]`